# Incompatible pointer types NSString and NSArray why?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(void)displayData:(NSString *)text{

  NSLog(@"DATA SEND");
  NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:text];
  NSString *separate = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"B"];
```

`separate` is the one that gives issue? How do I properly do this? I'm trying to perform a string split.

Comment: Look at the docs for `NSString componentsSeparatedByString:`. Notice the return type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`componentsSeparatedByString:` method returns `NSArray` not `NSString`, try that:

```
NSArray *seperate = [string1  componentsSeparatedByString:@"B"];
```

Answer (score -3):

what is that?

```
 NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:text];
```

Right way

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text];
```

or

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithString:text];
```

and then Grag answer.

Comment: No, the right way is simply `NSString *string1 = text;`.

Comment: or just NSArray *seperate = [text componetsSeperatedByString:@"B"]; ... ?